# How do I efficiently generate chunks to fill entire screen when my player moves?

Tags: java, procedural-generation, minecraft-modding

In my game I generate chunks when the player moves. The chunks are all generated on the fly, but currently I just created a simple flat 8X8 floor.  What happens is that when he moves to a new chunk the chunk in the direction of the player gets generated and its neighboring chunks.

This is not efficient because the generator does not fill the entire screen. I did try to use recursion but its not as fast as I would like it to be.

My question is what would be an efficient way of doing so? How does minecraft do so?
When I say this I mean just the way it PICKS which chunks to generate and in what order. Not how they generate or how they are saved in regions, just the order/way it generates them.

I just want to know what is a good way to load chunks around the player.

Comment: Are you looking for only how to load chunks efficiently around the player, or are you looking for a way to load chunks so that the entire screen is filled?

Comment: Both load chunks efficiently and to fill the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly...

Could you not just load the chunks in a spiral around the player? Each time you check for the next chunk to load you could start whole spiral process again (or come up with a better way to find 'missing' chunks) as this will loads the correct chunks whilst the player moves.

Comment: What should be my ending condition for my loop? When the chunk xy is outside of the screen?

Comment: Distance from player? Far enough away so it looks right